# Is it considered bad convention to put main() at the top of a C++ source?

Tags: c++, program-entry-point, conventions

Just starting with C++, I have done some coding in Java before and always in that language my tendency was to put the main method at the top of the class that invoked it.  Just made following the program logic easier and anyway felt more intuitive to me.  Now learning C++ and apparently it seems to be designed with the assumption that you put your main method at the bottom of your source file, since all methods it calls need to be declared first.  I am aware you can bypass this using method prototypes but is it considered bad practice to do this?  Makes me worry since the language seems to be designed with the assumption that you won't.  Don't want to develop a bad habit now when I am learning the language only to find out later people frown on it.

Comment: Don't worry your head about such things. In real life, you will have lots of source files & main will usually be in an independent file. In real life, all prototypes will be in a header file & you will `#include` them wherever needed.

Comment: As you said, you can forward-declare most things, more or less easily. Still, it's an added burden, and just liking your source-file-order upside-down is not enough reason for the inconvenience imho. Going against the grain just isn't worth the bother.

Comment: I don't know if it's convention or not but speaking from experience, yes. I usually expect `main()` to be towards the end of the source file, and to not do very much except call a few other functions.

Comment: I tend to put `main`() at the start so that when reading the file I can immediately see how the program flow is going.

Comment: I usually consider it a good practice to put as little code as possible in `main` and segregate `main` into its own file (`main.cpp` usually). From main you call the other code that actually does the work. For a very small project having all functionality in `main` (or in functions in the same file as `main`) is alright. In these cases I usually put main last for convenience sake. If you get to the point where it's hard to read you should probably start moving stuff into other files.

Comment: I suggest you to make the question "not opinion based". for example "Can I put main before anything else or is forbidden"? You can reask the question and even improve it and put a little search effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I like to put `main()` at the start of the file. Just make sure you have prototypes for functions invoked from main somewhere before main. Otherwise your code looks like Pascal - and that's just **so** wrong... :-) Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you *need* to *declare* everything you're gonna use *before* you use it.  And you *start* using things in `main()`.  So the *usual* construct is to put `main()` at the *end* of you're *main* compilation unit.

Comment: What's with *all* of the *strangely* placed *italics*?